# associate custom post type with tags with specific pages

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, tags

I have various products (custom post type)  which already have categories but I have now I have added this line to be able to add tags to the products.

```
'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
```

So, I have an industries section with various pages within that and for example one of them is called 'Woodworking'.  I have added the tag 'Woodworking' to various products and when someone visits /industry/woodworking I want those products to show up.

Is there an easy way to achieve this? I thought of perhaps using `WP_Query` but not sure how to create that relationship between the page name and the product tags.

EDIT:

I have done this which seems to work but not sure if the right way to go about it?

```
<?php $page_title = get_the_title(); ?>

<?php 
$tag_prods = new WP_Query(array(
    'tag' => 'Woodworking',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'Products',
    'order' => 'ASC'
    ));
?>

<?php if ($tag_prods->have_posts() ): while ($tag_prods->have_posts() ): $tag_prods->the_post(); ?>
    <?php foreach(get_the_tags() as $tags): ?>
        <?php if ($tags->name === $page_title): ?>
            <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Just noticed that this only works with single words. As soon as a tag word has a space in it then it doesn't pick it up.

Comment: The `tag` argument expects one or more tag *slugs* (e.g. `tag-name` and not `Tag Name`). See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/) for the full arguments list.

Comment: That helps, thank you!

Comment: @SallyCJ Can you add that as an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: I've just posted it as part of my answer.. I hope it helps you more. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have done this which seems to work but not sure if the right way to
>   go about it?

Yes, you can create a [custom Page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use) which displays posts in your custom post type, and use that template with those "industry" pages.

And if you want, you can create a single Page which will handle all the "industry" requests/URLs like `/industry/woodworking`. And then you can use [`add_rewrite_rule()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) to add a custom rewrite rule which redirects the requests to that Page.

Or you can also redirect them to the tag archives. Example:

```php
add_action( 'init', function(){
    add_rewrite_rule( '^industry/woodworking',
        'index.php?tag=woodworking&post_type=Products',
        'top' );
} );
```

> Just noticed that this only works with single words. As soon as a tag
>   word has a space in it then it doesn't pick it up.

As pointed in my comment, that's because the `tag` parameter expects one or more tag *slugs* and not names. Examples:

- `'tag' => 'tag-one, tag-two'` — correct.
- `'tag' => 'Tag One, Tag Two'` — incorrect.

You can check the full parameters list [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/#parameters).